# discord.js How can I create an invite for every server my bot is in?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to make a command, where I can get every guild invite that the bot is currently in

Answer (score 0):

`var invite = interaction.guild.invites.create(interaction.channel,{maxAge: 0}); interaction.channel.send(invite.code);`
Use this, for discord.js v13!
Replace interaction with var ex. msg (var on command method constructor)

Comment: var invite = message.guild.invites.create(message.channel, {
    maxAge: 0,
    });
    message.channel.send(invite);

Comment: im doing this but its showing error as "DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message"

Comment: That means the invitation failed to create, show your code and I can do more